# how do I change the path for non-admin user in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

In Windows XP I could change the PATH variable in the Control Panel / System Tool.

When I start "System" in the Win7 Control Panel I can see some information about the computer. At the link "Advanced system settings" I can open the "System Properties" dialog after UAC, that is similar to the Windows XP dialog. The "Environment Variables" button allows to change the environment variables.

BUT: The UAC has changed the user context and the settings that I can edit here is for the administrator account, not for me.

How do I change the environment variables for non administrative user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Start Menu - click on your user icon in the top right of the menu.  Select "change my environment variables" from the menu on the left hand of the screen.  Add your variables then click OK at the bottom of the dialogue box to save them.

Comment: Thanks, this works. For the files: You get to the same from Control Panel using the "User Accounts" link.